# What’s the correct way to create an NSURL from an NSString?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstring, nsurl

I’ve got an `NSString` that stores the path to a saved file:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"%@/someFolder/%@",
                      NSHomeDirectory(),
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.fileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"]]];
```

And it’s OK — when I log it, I get:

```
/Users/username/someFolder/fileName.txt
```

So my next step is to make an `NSURL` object from this `NSString`. I did this:

```
        NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filePath]];
        NSLog(@"URL = %@", pathURL);
```

but the response is:

```
URL = (null)
```

What’s wrong here? How can I do this correctly?

Comment: not your issue but you can change your pathURL line to just be `NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];`

Comment: Why not `NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];` ?

Comment: I checked same code... URL is giving correct value!!!

Comment: Two other problems: First, you're creating a folder within the Home folder, which is improper; only the user and the operating system should be doing that. Create your folder in Application Support instead. Second, you're stapling paths together (using `stringWithFormat:`, no less) instead of asking an NSFileManager for the correct URL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A path is not a valid URL by itself. You have to use this:

```
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

And read the documentation. (And don’t overuse / abuse format strings.)